# WTForms FieldList with optional fields

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have the following form,

```
class AddForm(wtf.Form):
    tags = TagListField("Tags (comma separated)", validators=[wtf.Required()])
    question = wtf.TextField("Question", validators=[wtf.Required()])
    answers = wtf.FieldList(wtf.TextField("Answer", validators=[wtf.Required()]), min_entries=2, max_entries=5)
```

And I have a form setup to display this form along with a button that adds more "answers" inputs dynamically (by the user clicking a button). However, when the form gets submitted, any fields that are added but not filled in are considered errors.

Specifically, if I have 3 inputs for "Answer", but I only fill in the first two, then the third one comes up as an error, even though I have specified that the minimum number of entries is 2. It seems like it should ignore this data.

Since I am using this with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) I am going to just modify the `request.form` data to ignore blank fields. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: check out the docs  they have a section on `dynamic form composition` http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specific_problems.html

Answer (score 4):

May be your the

```
 validators=[wtf.Required()])
```

is an issue ? Have you tried changing it to

```
validators=[wtf.Optional()])
```

Comment: I ended up just processing the form data on my own and it seems to have fixed itself without any problems. I believe the fix was to change it to `wtf.DataRequired` instead of `wtf.Required`.